# Installing new SODIMM RAM for laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, bios

My laptop is the following:

```
Dell Inspiron 1764
i3 M 300 @ 2.13GHz
```

Originally it came with 3GB RAM. I run Windows 7 64bit.

So I have bought the following SODIMM RAM for my laptop, in order to increase the RAM:

2 x `Kingston ValueRAM (1x, 4GB, DDR3-1600, SODIMM 204)`

The sticks are 1600MHz and my laptop runs 1066Mhz. I thought that buying a higher MHz wouldn't matter as the sticks will simply run at the lower frequency. Also, according to several websites, this RAM type would be compatible with my laptop. Well, not!

With the new RAM sticks installed, it won't show the Windows logo and keeps looping to the screen where you can choose between '*normal*' and '*system check*'. Both don't work and reinitiate the loop. However, BIOS *does* recognize the RAM as can be seen in the picture below (Memory: 8055MB).

What I've tried:

- Installing a [new BIOS version](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R301041) (to A13). But the BIOS Setup Utility still shows version **A04**?
- Trying all possible combinations of the RAM sticks (including combinations with the old sticks)

Is there anything else I can try?

Below are pictures of my BIOS Setup Utility and the specifications on the Kingston RAM:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you try it with just one of your new sticks, and then the other (and try each one individually in both slots), does it work for either? Also, when you put your old sticks back in and boot into Windows, is there anything interesting in the event log (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> System; look for errors and warnings corresponding to the time when you last tried to boot with your new sticks)?

Comment: I already tried all combinations. Including the old sticks. For the logs: I couldn't really find anything except an error stating that the 'EC (embedded controller) didn't respond in time. This can be due to a mistake in the EC-hardware or firmware, or that the BIOS is trying to get access to the EC in a wrong manner.'

Comment: @Ramhound: which display is unreadable? To me the picture is visible. Try this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Lry.jpg

Comment: @Ramhound Machine wouldn't even start if rams are incompatible. Jean, if you have successfully updated your BIOS, it should show new version number. I suggest try again. Also you can try booting with another OS if you are able to.

Comment: My browser decided to half load the image then place red and blue lines in the image.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's what I thought :P

Comment: @Haplo: Thank you, I will try rebooting again. Should I use the `FLASHME_v103_Win_1194_4M_1764A13.exe` from [this link](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=R301041)?

Comment: 1) As far as I can see this should just work. Max supported RAM is 8GB, and it needs 533MHz (real) / 1066 MHz (marketing) / PC3-8500 SoDIMMs.
2) However, can you verify your "system memory" with the old RAM inserted? I find the 628KB in the picture rather surprising. I expected either 512KB or 512+128 (640) KB.  Not 628.

Comment: If you put JUST your old RAM back in now, does Windows boot? With the new RAM in, can you boot to another OS (like a Linux LiveCD)? Have you tried going into Windows 7's Safe Mode yet?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: with old RAM it boots. Haven't tried booting to other OS (I don't have Linux LiveCD). Haven't tried going into Safe Mode. I'll try doing the latter one now.

Comment: @Hennes: The "system memory" is the same with the old RAM. Also 628KB. I just tested it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: Like I said before, with the old RAM it boots. I can't go into Windows 7's Safe Mode. Actually I can't do any of the options listed when I press f8. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jean-Paul Yeah, but how did you flash BIOS? From Windows? If that doesn't/didn't work, follow [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/136987/how-to-create-a-bootable-dos-usb-drive/) guide to create a bootable USB DOS drive to flash BIOS.

Comment: @Haplo: Yes I did it from Windows. Thank I'll try that out.